# При подключении к сети OpenVPN ПК теряет доступ к Интернету

Tags: ubuntu, сеть, iptables, openvpn

Есть 2 компьютера:

- С - OpenVPN сервер в интернете с белым IP (ОС: Ubuntu 20.04)
- К - Клиент, домашний компьютер (ОС: Ubuntu 18.04)

При подключении компьютера К к сети OpenVPN, запущенной на сервере С, компьютер К теряет подключение к интернету, хотя К и С могут пинговать друг друга в сети OpenVPN. При отключении К от сети OpenVPN, подключение восстанавливается. Также можно подключиться к К по SSH через проброшенный порт на С. Перед этим были проброшены порты командами:

```bsh
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 2222 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i eth0 --dport 2222 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.8.0.2:22
```

`10.8.0.1` - адрес С в сети OpenVPN; `10.8.0.2` - адрес К в сети OpenVPN

Как можно починить это, чтобы весь трафик шел через OpenVPN, и К все также имел доступ к интернету?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте в настройках сети поставить галочку "Use this connection only for resources on its network", то есть использовать соединение только для той сети, для которой впн был разрешён

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]